# How to handle complex table relationship with flask sqlalchemy

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I am developing a simple forms website using `flask WTForms` and populating the data into a database. I am having trouble with sqlalchemy relationship between the tables.

The basic scenario is the user fills in the house hold data and that gets added to the database then fills in the car info, that also gets to the database and so on. The actual workflow of the site is shown here:

[image]

Here is my code shown below:

The household db

```
class HouseholdDB(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "data"
    __table_args__ = {"schema": "transportation"}
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    no_of_adults_above_15 = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    no_of_adults_under_15 = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    carinfodb_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(CarInfoDB.id))
    childandadultinfodb = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(ChildAndAdultInfoDB.id))
    personaldatadb = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(PersonalDataDB.id))
    traveldiarydb = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(TravelDiaryDB.id))

    def __init__(
        self,
        no_of_adults_above_15,
        no_of_adults_under_15,
    ):
        self.no_of_adults_above_15 = no_of_adults_above_15
        self.no_of_adults_under_15 = no_of_adults_under_15
```

The car info db

```
class CarInfoDB(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "car_info"
    __table_args__ = {"schema": "transportation"}
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(HouseholdDB.id), primary_key=True)
    make = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    model = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    mileage = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)

    household_id = relationship(
        "HouseholdDB", back_populates="carinfodb", uselist=False
    )

    def __init__(self, make, model, car_age, transmission, mileage):
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.mileage = mileage
```

The child and adult info db

```
class ChildAndAdultInfoDB(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "child_adult_info"
    __table_args__ = {"schema": "transportation"}
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    age_under_15 = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    is_child_schooling = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False)
    school_location = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)

    household_id = relationship(
        "HouseholdDB", back_populates="childandadultdb", uselist=False
    )

    def __init__(
        self,
        age_under_15,
        is_child_schooling,
        school_location,
    ):
        self.age_under_15 = age_under_15
        self.is_child_schooling = is_child_schooling
        self.school_location = school_location
```

The personal data db

```
class PersonalDataDB(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "personal_data"
    __table_args__ = {"schema": "transportation"}
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    gender = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    age = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    car = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    taxi = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)

    household_id = relationship(
        "HouseholdDB", back_populates="personaldatadb", uselist=False
    )

    def __init__(
        self,
        gender,
        age,
        car,
        taxi,
    ):

        self.gender = gender
        self.age = age
        self.car = car
        self.taxi = taxi
```

Then the last form on the site;

```
class TravelDiaryDB(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "travel_diary"
    __table_args__ = {"schema": "transportation"}
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    location = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    whereabout = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)

    household_id = relationship(
        "HouseholdDB", back_populates="traveldiarydb", uselist=False
    )

    def __init__(
        self,
        location,
        whereabout,
    ):
        self.location = location
        self.whereabout = whereabout
```

When I add data for the household data and submit I get the following errors: `sqlalchemy.exc.AmbiguousForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship HouseholdDB.carinfodb - there are multiple foreign key paths linking the tables.  Specify the 'foreign_keys' argument, providing a list of those columns which should be counted as containing a foreign key reference to the parent table.`

I have tried several approaches such as the one here: [sqlalchemy : Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45406332/sqlalchemy-could-not-determine-join-condition-between-parent-child-tables) but doesnt seem to work

Answer (score 0):

Your `CarInfoDB.id` is a foreign key of `HouseholdDB.id`

**and**

`HouseholdDB.carinfodb_id` is a foreign key of `CarInfoDB.id`

This means that `HouseholdDB.carinfodb_id` = `HouseholdDB.id` = `CarInfoDB.id`

Did you mean to define `CarInfoDB.id` as a foreign key of `HouseholdDB.id`? If not your problem is solved by just replacing

```
class CarInfoDB(UserMixin, db.Model):
   [...]
   id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(HouseholdDB.id), primary_key=True)
```

with

```
class CarInfoDB(UserMixin, db.Model):
   [...]
   id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
```

Otherwise `CarInfoDB.id` is redundant